# QT String to char * adds extra characters

Tags: qt

I have a `qTextEdit` that I grab the text from (`QString`) and convert to a `char*` with this code:

```
QString msgQText = ui->textMsg->toPlainText();
size_t textSize = (size_t)msgQText.size();

if (textSize > 139) {
    textSize = 139;
}

unsigned char * msgText = (unsigned char *)malloc(textSize);

memcpy(msgText, msgQText.toLocal8Bit().data(), textSize);

msgText[textSize] = '\0';

if (textSize > 0) {
    Msg * newTextMsg = new Msg;
    newTextMsg->type = 1;  // text message type
    newTextMsg->bitrate = 0;
    newTextMsg->samplerate = 0;
    newTextMsg->bufSize = (int)textSize;
    newTextMsg->len = 0;
    newTextMsg->buf = (char *)malloc(textSize);
    memcpy((char *)newTextMsg->buf, (char *)msgText, textSize);

    lPushToEnd(sendMsgList, newTextMsg, sizeof(Msg));

    ui->sendRecList->addItem((char *)newTextMsg->buf);

    ui->textMsg->clear();
}
```

I put the text into a `qListBox`, but it shows up like [image: wrong text]

However, the character array, if I print it out, does not have the extra characters.

I have tried checking the "**compile using UTF-8**" option, but it doesn't make a difference.

Also, I send the text using **RS232**, and the receiver side also displays the extra characters.

The receiver code is here:

```
m_serial->waitForReadyRead(200);
const QByteArray data = m_serial->readAll();
if (data.size() > 0) {
    qDebug() << "New serial data: "  << data;

    QString str = QString(data);
    if (str.contains("0x6F8C32E90A")) {
        qDebug() << "TEST SUCCESSFUL!";
    }

    return data.data();
} else {
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: Note that you're writing off the end of the allocated buffer when you do `msgText[textSize] = '\0';`.  That's undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a difference between the size of a `QString` and the size of the QByteArray returned by `toLocal8Bit()`. A `QString` contains unicode text stored as UTF-16, while a `QByteArray` is "just" a `char[]`.

A `QByteArray` is null-terminated, so you do not need to add it manually.

As @GM pointed out: `msgText[textSize] = '\0';` is undefined behavior. You are writing to the `textSize + 1` position of the `msgText` array.
This position may be owned by something else and may be overwritten, so you end up with a non null terminated string.

This should work:

```
QByteArray bytes = msgQText.toLocal8Bit();
size_t textSize = (size_t)bytes.size() + 1; // Add 1 for the final '\0'
unsigned char * msgText = (unsigned char *) malloc(textSize);
memcpy(msgText, bytes.constData(), textSize);
```

Additional tips:

- Prefer using const functions on Qt types that are copy-on-write, e.g. use `QBytearray::constData()` instead of `QByteArray::data()`. The non-const functions can cause a deep-copy of the object.
- Do not use `malloc()` and other C-style functions if possible. Here you could do:
  `unsigned char * msgText = new unsigned char[textSize];` and  later `delete[] msgText;`.
- Prefer using C++ casts (static_cast, reinterpret_cast, etc.) instead of C-style casts.
- You are making 2 copies of the text (2 calls to `memcpy`), given your code only 1 seem to be enough.